# preg_match() seems to always return 0 matches

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following pattern and subject

```php
$pattern = "\[item\s*id=['\"](.*?)['\"]\s*\]";
$subject = "[item id=\"40\"]";
```

Basically, I want to get the id attribute from a string, `[item id="30"]`.

And I've tested my pattern and subject on different [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) websites and they all return the correct matches.

However, the following code I wrote seems to always return NULL for matches.

```php
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

What’s wrong? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing delimiters:

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /data/1.php on line 4 NULL
```

So `$pattern` should look like:

```
$pattern = "~\[item\s*id=['\"](.*?)['\"]\s*\]~";
```

It returns:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "[item id="40"]" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "40" } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use proper [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Also, [this site](http://regexpal.com/) is very helpful in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try rather this:

```
$pattern = '/\[item\s+id=[\'"](.*)[\'"]\s*\]/';
```

For instance:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/\[item\s+id=[\'"](.*)[\'"]\s*\]/';
$subject = "[item id=\"40\"]";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0]; # => 40
?>
```

You have to use proper delimiters (`/…/`) and `\s+` should be more appropriate than `\s*` so it doesn't match something like `[itemid="2"]`.

Comment: @CurryIng this should be the best answer I suppose, since in a right syntax the number of space between `item` & `id` should not be equal to none.